# How do I play a video clip in reverse

Tags: video, media, media-player

While watching [Lego DC Comics Super Heroes: The Flash (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7877382/), there is a particular sequence when Barry is visiting Dr. Fate. He meets with Zatanna there who, as is common in the DC Universe, speaks in reverse ([backwards magic](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/dc-comics-2454/backwards-magic-1509642/)).

Is there some way that I can play a video in reverse so that I get to understand what was being said instead of having to rely on subtitles?

Answer (score 0):

trim that part

Use these apps to convert

Android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.bizo.reverse&hl=en

iphone
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reverse-vid-video-rewind-editor-for-backwards-instant/id950551948?mt=8

windows
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/reverse-video/9nblggh5x1rl

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.

Comment: I use Windows 7 (or debian) and do not own/have android/iphone. Any other alternatives?